# In SSRS How to make a sequential Group Column

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I want to make a Sequential Group Column with the help of Matrix in SQL Server Reporting Service (SSRS),

[image]

In the image above, there are Dates with Days name, Mon 24, Tue 25 and Fri 28, So I want to make it like that: Keep the sequence of Dates, no matter whether the data is available or not.

[image]

My SQL Query for generating that data is:

```
SELECT tl.[Job No_] + ' - ' + j.[Description] AS [Job Name]        
      ,tl.[Job Task No_] + ' - ' + w.[Description] AS [WBS Code]
      ,pt.[Description] AS [Pay Type]
      ,tlt.[Period Date]          
      ,tlt.[Hours] AS [Hours]
 FROM TimesheetLine tl 
 JOIN TimesheetLineDate tld ON tl.[Rec ID] = tld.[Timesheet Line Rec ID]
 JOIN TimesheetLineTransactions tlt ON tld.[Rec ID] = tlt.[Timesheet Line Date Rec ID]
 LEFT JOIN Job j ON tl.[Job No_] = j.[No_]
 LEFT JOIN JobWBS w ON w.[Job Task No_] = tl.[Job Task No_]
 LEFT JOIN PayType pt ON tl.[Pay Type] = pt.[Name]
 LEFT JOIN Timesheet t ON tl.[Timesheet Rec ID] = t.[Rec ID]
 WHERE tl.[Timesheet Rec ID] = @RecId AND t.[Resource No_] = @UserResourceNo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSRS cannot generate data so you will need to solve this in your dataset.

I would add a right join to a table of Dates e.g. a Date/Time Dimension table.  Then I would use the date from that table as the label and values for the SSRS Column Group.